# GLPK/GMPL: Minimize objective function but keep it > 0

Tags: constraints, ampl, glpk, mathprog, objective-function

I am trying to minimize an objective function that has three parameters: i, p, j like this:

```
param mlu{i in I, p in P, j in out[p]} := traffic[i,p]/capacity[j];
minimize MAXLU{i in I, p in P, j in out[p]}: mlu[i,p,j] * x[i,p,j];
```

but the objective function has to be greater than 0, otherwise it is defeating my purpose of minimization.

And I am trying to ensure this by adding a constraint on the objective function like this:

```
s.t. constraint1{i in I, p in P, j in out[p]} : MAXLU[i,p,j] != 0;
```

But I get the following error:

```
LP.mod:66: invalid reference to status, primal value, or dual value of objective MAXLU above solve statement

Context:  i in I , p in P , j in out [ p ] } : MAXLU [ i , p , j ] !=
glp_mpl_generate: invalid call sequence
Error detected in file glpapi14.c at line 79
Aborted
```

Is it even possible to do this? Thank you for any help/suggestions!

Comment: How about defining some very small value `e` and add `obj >= e`?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to variables and parameters, but not objectives (`MAXLU`) in a constraint. A simple way to fix this is to replace `MAXLU` in `constraint1` with the actual objective expression:

```
s.t. constraint1{i in I, p in P, j in out[p]} : mlu[i,p,j] * x[i,p,j] ...;
```

Moreover, you cannot define a constraint with expression != 0. You can have >= `epsilon` or <= `epsilon` instead where `epsilon` is a small number:

```
s.t. constraint1{i in I, p in P, j in out[p]} : mlu[i,p,j] * x[i,p,j] >= epsilon;
```